# Sort Array by Alphabetical order using SelectionSort without Array.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, netbeans, compare

I am referencing my code to mathebits website on SelectionSorting, changing the variables accordingly from `int` to `String` for my case, and adding in sort by alphabetical order as well.

Below is my current code for `SelectionSort` of students by `lastName`:

```
public static void SelectionSort(Student[] st) {
        int i, j, first;
        String temp;
        String jLastName = "";
        String firstLastName = "";
        String iLastName ="";
        for (i = st.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            first = 0;   
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            {
                if (st[j].getLastName() != null) {

                    jLastName=st[j].getLastName();

                    if (st[first].getLastName() != null) {

                        firstLastName = st[first].getLastName();

                        if ((jLastName.compareToIgnoreCase(firstLastName)) > 0) {
                            first = j;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            iLastName = st[i].getLastName();
            temp = firstLastName;
            firstLastName = iLastName;
            iLastName = temp;
        }
    }
```

The code does not give me error. However, the output does not show that it has been sorted according to alphabetical order.

Comment: `String.compareTo()` isn't comparing `String` lengths...

Comment: @FlorentBayle I see! My misinterpretation! I will try again

Comment: Method calls are no valid target for assignments. Most likely you should swap the students anyway, instead of changing their last names.

Comment: I don' t think your task is to switch only the lastname of the student objects. The firstnames will not be fitting anymore. Better to switch the object references. Student temp; temp = st[first]; st[first] = st[i]; st[i]=temp;

Comment: Swap the student objects not the name which is just a value within the object

Comment: I have made updates to my code. It does not display error, however the results are not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant compare two String like number, instead use compareTo method in String like:

```
if (st[..].getLastName().compareTo(..) < 0) {..
```

Also to change value, you need to have new Setter method in Student like:

```
public void setLastName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And then you could call it like:

```
st[..].setName(st[i].getName());
```

Comment: I don't think the students' last names should be changed, if the task is to *"[...] sort an array by studentName, by alphabetical order."*

Comment: I have made updates to my code. It does not display error, however the results are not sorted.